# excel linked accounts of members to their savings,withdraws and loans

Tags: account

we have a community savings and credit society. In excel how should i generate linked tables of accounts of savings, withdrawal and loans of members.

i did make tables in excel and added the followings
name of member, withdraw , savings and loans